# vim syntax match is wrong ([A-Z] is matching all alphabetic characters)

Tags: regex, vim, syntax

I have a .vimrc file that contains the following line:

```
syntax match proper /\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*/
```

In theory, it should match any set of alphabetic characters that is prefixed by a space and starts with a capital letter. This works as it should when I run it with vim 7.3 on Ubuntu 11.11. However, when I sent the .vimrc to a server running vim 7.0 on CentOS 5.6, it matches **all** words prefixed by a space, not just the words that start with a capital letter.

I've been searching for a few hours to figure this out, but I'm baffled. I tried `[[:upper:]]` instead of `[A-Z]` but it came up with the same results. Using `/[A-Z]` and `/[[:upper:]]` to search properly selects only uppercase characters. Running `ls | grep "[A-Z]"` in bash only highlights files with uppercase characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My next best guess (after ignorecase) would be an error in the configuration of the syntax highlighting script itself:

Some languages are not case sensitive, such as Pascal.  Others, such as C, are
case sensitive.  You need to tell which type you have with the following
commands:

```
:syntax case match
:syntax case ignore
```

Could you try what happens when you specifically add `:syntax case match` to the mix (or spot where a spurious `ignore` is coming from)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you accidentally turned `ignorecase` on? What do you get with `/\s\C[A-Z]\c[A-Z]*/`?

Comment: You should actually word it as an answer. Right now it should a comment. I suspect this really should be the answer, anyway so I'd suggest rewording.

Comment: `ignorecase` and `smartcase` are both off. `/\s\C[A-Z]\c[A-Z]*/` selected the exact same text as `/\s[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*/` did, unfortunately.

Comment: @sehe Sometimes my answer morphs into a comment or vice versa while I'm composing it. Sorry about that.